# How to add Redux store to React Native app created using create-react-native-app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've created a React Native app according to documentation, but when I want to add the Redux store, I find that there is no index.js or index.ios.js file to which I can wrap the Redux store.

When I create the index.js myself, I have no idea how to change the entry point of the application so it uses index.js instead of the default App.js. I feel like it should be something easy and obvious, but after googling for hours, it seems like I have two options. One, to use the App.js file like the index file, or to eject the application (which I don't want to do).

Comment: though this is a project created by `react-native-cli` , but latest version of react-native will create only index.js file for projects created with `react-native-cli`. https://github.com/shubhnik/redux-react-navigation/blob/master/App.js , you can see how store is created.

Comment: @ShubhnikSingh THANKS! Saved me hours of frustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a file in the root called App.js, that is the entry point for your React Native App.

In there you should import/define your store and then, in the render method wrap your navigation solution with the Provider this way so that all your containers can be connected to redux:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Provider store={store}>
            <Navigation />
          </Provider>
        </View>
    );   }
```